# Communication between FiftyOne and CVAT containers using Traefik and HTTP on port 8080

Tags: networking, docker-compose, traefik, cvat, fiftyone

I am setting up CVAT and FiftyOne on a server, and I am having trouble with the communication between both applications.

I followed CVAT self-hosted [installation instructions](https://opencv.github.io/cvat/docs/administration/basics/installation/#ubuntu-1804-x86_64amd64) to setup CVAT.
This includes several containers among which `cvat_server` and `traefik` as well as a `cvat_cvat` network, all defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file of [cvat source code](https://github.com/opencv/cvat/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml).
I defined `127.0.0.1` as host for CVAT prior to launching the containers, with `export CVAT_HOST=127.0.0.1`.
The port for CVAT server is 8080.

I have written another `docker-compose.yml` file to define my FiftyOne container, based on the example at the end of the [page for the FiftyOne Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/voxel51/fiftyone/).
In this file, I linked the FiftyOne container with the `cvat_cvat` network.
I also included Traefik labels.
The contents of FiftyOne's `docker-compose.yml` file are:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  fiftyone:
    command: ['python', '/usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages/fiftyone/server/main.py', '--port', '5151']
    environment:
      FIFTYONE_DEFAULT_APP_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0
    image: voxel51/fiftyone:latest
    ports:
      - 5151:5151
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /path/to/fiftyon/shared
        target: /fiftyone
    networks:
      - cvat_cvat
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.fiftyone.loadbalancer.server.port=5151
      - traefik.http.routers.fiftyone.rule=Host(`${CVAT_HOST:-localhost}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.fiftyone.entrypoints=web
networks:
  cvat_cvat:
    external: true
```

I am having trouble sending annotations requests from the FiftyOne container the CVAT server container. From the host machine, I can curl the CVAT server: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080`. But from within the FiftyOne container, the same curl command fails (returns `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused`).

How can I configure my containers to allow HTTP traffic on port 8080 from the FiftyOne to the CVAT container?

For information, I managed to allow communication by setting the FiftyOne container in host network mode (i.e. by adding `network_mode: "host"` in the FiftyOne `docker-compose.yml` file). But I would like to use Traefik for this issue because, if I understand correctly: 1/ Traefik is already setup by CVAT self-hosted installation and is designed to handle such issues, 2/ the host network mode solution removes the purpose of container isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by the address I used to communicate from the FiftyOne container to the CVAT container.
127.0.0.1 (localhost) within a container is always the container's localhost, and not the host's.
Containers on the same network are discoverable by their service's name (as described in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)).
So my case is solved when using `curl http://cvat_server:8080` from within the FiftyOne container.

As a side note, I now understand that Traefik handles communication from the outside world to my infrastructure, and not communication within my infrastructure (answers point 1/ in last paragraph of my question).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Traefik for managing this kind of communication — FastAPI has worked for me pretty well in the past.

If you're set on using Traefik, then here are a few debugging tips that may help:

- ensure Traefik is running as expected, and that both containers are connected to the network
- use container names directly rather than env vars
- check firewall settings, and make sure that requests are being forwarded as expected.

All of that said, I personally prefer using FastAPI if you need to run separate containers. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In the end the issue I had was not related with Traefik, which handles communication from the outside to my infrastructure, but with my usage of Docker Compose, as I write in my answer.